# How to move to next entries according to the recno in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paging

I have four buttons first,last,previous and next button if a user clicks on first button then the min no of recno have to be dispalyed and if the user clicks on next then the minof next no entries have to be displayed..my problem is i didn't get any error and i have four buttons..(First,next,prev,last) none of the buttons are working..Help me to move to the next entries according to the recno..Thanks in advance....
This is my controller code:

```
    $first = $this->db->query('SELECT MIN(recno) AS `first` FROM `daybook` ORDER BY recno DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();

        $firstID = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `daybook`  where recno='$first[first]' ORDER BY recno ASC")->result_array();
        //$firstID = $firstIDQuery->result_array();
         $last = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(recno) AS `last` FROM `daybook` ORDER BY recno DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();
        $lastID = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `daybook` where recno='$last[last]'  ORDER BY recno")->result_array();
        //$lastID = $lastIDQuery->result_array();

        $id = 1;
        if(!empty($id)){
       $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM daybook WHERE recno = $id")->result_array();
   }
            //$result = $resultQuery->result_array();

        $data['currentID'] = $id;
        $data['firstID'] = $first;
        $data['lastID'] = $last;
        $data['result'] = $result;
        $this->load->view('BookKeeping/DayBookEntry', $data, FALSE);
```

This is my view page:

```
 <ul class='pagination'>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$firstID; ?>' class='button'>First</a><br>
        <?php
            if($currentID != $firstID){
                foreach ($result as $next_key => $next_value) {
                    if($currentID == $next_value['recno']){
                        $nextID = $result[$next_key]++;
                    }
                }}
        ?>
            <a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$nextID['recno']; ?>' class='button'>Next</a><br>
        <?php
            if($currentID != $lastID){
                foreach ($result as $prev_key => $prev_value) {
                    if($currentID == $prev_value['recno']){
                        $prevID = $result[$prev_key]--;
                        }
}}
        ?>


            <a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$prevID['recno']; ?>' class='button'>Previous</a><br>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$lastID; ?>' class='button'>Last</a><br>
    </ul>
```

It's printing correct value in first,last,next,prev i checked it by using print_r(exp)..and my problem is how to display it in link(href links)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Nothing happens? Behaviour is not what you expected? Buttons not getting rendered? Buttons get rendered but the `href` part is missing, broken, wrong?

Comment: When i click on the first it have to move to min recno but in my case it's not moving to minimum entry it's same for all the buttons

Comment: I'm a bit troubled by the fact that you're only using single quotes on everything instead of correctly using single and double quotes. This is most likely preventing your links to be formed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working answer
Controller Code:

```
$first = $this->db->query('SELECT MIN(recno) AS `first` FROM `daybook` ORDER BY recno DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();

    $firstID = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `daybook`  where recno='$first[first]' ORDER BY recno ASC")->result_array();
    //$firstID = $firstIDQuery->result_array();
    $last = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(recno) AS `last` FROM `daybook` ORDER BY recno DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();
    $lastID = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `daybook` where recno='$last[last]'  ORDER BY recno")->result_array();
    //$lastID = $lastIDQuery->result_array();

    //$id = 1;
    if(!empty($id)){
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM daybook WHERE recno = $id")->row_array();
    }else{
        $result = "";
    }

    $allData = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM daybook ORDER BY recno ASC")->result_array();

        //$result = $resultQuery->result_array();

    if(!empty($id)){
        $data['currentID'] = $id;
    }else {
        $data['currentID'] = $first['first'];
    }
    $data['firstID'] = $first;
    $data['lastID'] = $last;
    $data['result'] = $result;
    $data['allData'] = $allData;
```

View Page:

```
 <a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$firstID['first']; ?>' class='button'><i class="icon-first">First</i></a><br><br>
                                <?php
                                    if($currentID != $lastID['last']){
                                        foreach ($allData as $next_key => $next_value) {
                                            //echo $next_key+1;
                                            //echo '<pre>';print_r($next_value);exit();
                                            if($currentID == $next_value['recno']){
                                               $nextID = $allData[$next_key+1];

                                            }
                                        }
                                        $anchorTagNext = base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$nextID['recno'];
                                    }else {
                                        $anchorTagNext = '#';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                    <a href='<?php echo $anchorTagNext; ?>' class='button'><i class="icon-next">Next</i></a><br><br>
                                <?php
                                    if($currentID != $firstID['first']){
                                        foreach ($allData as $prev_key => $prev_value) {
                                            //echo '<pre>';print_r($prev_value);exit();

                                            if($currentID == $prev_value['recno']){
                                                //echo $allData[$prev_key-1]['recno'];exit();
                                               $prevId = $allData[$prev_key-1];
                                            }
                                        }
                                        $anchorTagPrevious = base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$prevId['recno'];
                                    } else {
                                        $anchorTagPrevious = '#';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                <a href='<?php echo $anchorTagPrevious; ?>' class='button'><i class="icon-previous">Previous</i></a><br><br>
                                <a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$lastID['last']; ?>' class='button'><i class="icon-last">Last</i></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing single quotes on everything instead of using a combination of single and double quotes where appropriate, which is messing with your links being created correctly.

Instead of

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url().'/BookKeeping/daybook/'.$nextID['recno']; ?>' class='button'>Next</a><br>
```

Try

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('BookKeeping/daybook/'.$nextID['recno']; ?>" class="button">Next</a>
```